# find the last 3 different thing order on date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I wanna find the last 3 people in order on date in my table but i don't know how I could write that
here is my sample code:

```
SELECT TOP 3 ActionDate
FROM ActivityTable
GROUP BY ActorCode
ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
```

| ActionDate | ActorCode |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | 963 |
| 2020-01-01 | 963 |
| 2019-12-12 | 256 |
| 2019-12-30 | 256 |

output:

| ActionDate | ActorCode |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | 963 |
| 2019-12-30 | 256 |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your query would seem to do what you want.

Comment: you consider that as a simple Login activity table

Comment: . . I really have no idea what *you* mean by "simple login activity table".

Comment: @SaraMoradi please describe what output you want in select, and some sample data. I guess every ActorCode has multiple ActionDate and you want only top 3 ActorCode ordered by max(ActionDate) ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you selecting dates if you want people?  I suspect you may want the last three `ActorCode`.  If so use aggregation:

```
SELECT TOP (3) ActorCode
FROM ActivityTable a
GROUP BY ActorCode
ORDER BY MAX(ActionDate) DESC
```

Comment: in front of the SELECT why I can't write other columns? it gave me an error!